# Creating Random Images

Tags: javascript, image, math, random, submit

I have an assignment, where I have to create a JavaScript based application (which I've done already)< but my problem now is that I've got to use two text boxes, one is to enter your name and the other is to enter your surname. Once you entered that, and click on the submit button, I need a random image (out of five) to appear and then slowly jump around the app page. I know I've got to use the Math random code. But I've got no idea how to use the submit to then generate a different picture (out of five) each time I click submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your images in an array and then use math.random between 0 and 4 to get your random image. You put all of this stuff in a function and trigger the function onsubmit.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var image_urls = [ "1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png" ];
var selected_image;

function PickImage()
{
    selected_image = image_urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * image_urls.length)];
    document.getElementById("image_element").src = selected_image;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id='image_element'>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="PickImage()" />
```